# Is takeoff permitted from an aerodrome inside a CTR when it's outside the tower's operating hours?

Tags: airspace, icao

I am departing from an airfield which is within the CTR of a nearby airport but outside tower operating hours. The chart doesn't specify this situation.

According to ICAO rules,

Am I allowed to take off or not?

EDIT: this is not an EASA or FAA specific question. Rather international, ICAO rules, but if there are different conventions it's also good to know.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add EASA tags, and/or mention the country in plain language.

Comment: Yes, but my question is not EASA nor FAA specific.

Comment: Well, the answers might be though...  You specified LESL, which when I looked it up is in Spain.  But I see you have since deleted it.  Really, valid answers will depend on the airspace classification and rules for the country you are in.  I don't think there is a single answer that will cover every scenario, and your question was probably better before with a specific example.

Comment: Also, VFR or IFR?

Comment: VFR of course. My expectation is that class D will revert to E or G as stated in your answer, but it's more general in the sense of. What if it's not specified in the chart? Can an airspace class D exists without ATC at time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...  What if what is not specified in the chart?  If Class D exists it would be depicted, if it is not depicted there is no Class D.  Right?

Comment: I don't mean in case the class D is not specified. I mean if what happens outside the ATS hours is not specified.

Comment: I think the question is clear. If the answer is "nobody knows", fine, but I don't think there is an issue with this question.

Comment: Re "Yes, but my question is not EASA nor FAA specific."-- I don't think that's true.  For example, I don't think the question is meaningful at all in the context of the US.  I don't think the phrase "aerodrome inside of a CTR" has any meaning in that context.  Of course, I may be wrong-- but I would hope the question would have some content that would educate me on the error of my ways if that were the case.  Anyway I live in the US and have no idea what a "CTR" is.

Comment: Re "VFR of course. My expectation is that class D will revert to E or G as stated in your answer, but it's more general in the sense of. What if it's not specified in the chart? Can an airspace class D exists without ATC at time? –" -- in the US, it's never specified on the chart what the airspace reverts to when the tower is closed.  (Except in the cases where there is an "extension" adjoining.)  You have to check the Chart Supplement.

Comment: But I'm sure that in the US, it is never intended that the airspace remains Class D when the tower is closed.

Comment: Different countries have different ways of dealing with what happens with airspace outside ATS operating hours. It is impossible to answer this question without you specifying a jurisdiction

Comment: @quietflyer: "*I live in the US and have no idea what a "CTR" is*". in the ICAO wording CTR is a controlled traffic region, generally below a TMA, managing arrivals and departures to/from an airfield. Used in most countries, in Europe but not limited to. For FAA it should be a class D airspace managed by a TRACON.

Comment: @expeditedescent What's the ICAO standard? Normally if an ICAO member doesn't respect it, should publish a difference. I am more interested in the rule, not the exceptions.

Comment: @quietflyer I am surprised to learn there are no CTRs in the US. I flew in Europe and America and there were CTRs everywhere, but I never flew in the US.

Comment: @Gus The FAA has a way of doing everything differently from the rest of the world :)

Comment: If this question were edited to say "According to ICAO rules" at the front, would it answerable?  I'm not knowledgable about ICAO rules to know if that would make sense, but I hate to see to this question be closed.  Yes you could argue that that would invalidate an existing answer but in this case perhaps the answer should not have been offered yet if the question clearly needed some work.  Anyway I'd suggest you make that edit Gus and then I suspect people will vote to re-open.

Comment: (I mean, you already did, w/ the last sentence, and looks like people are already voting to reopen, but you could put it at the front for more clarity.)

Comment: Done, if you manage to re-open I will accept answers. Even stuff like "It's not really specified." or "It should be written in the chart, If it's not nobody knows".

Answer (score 4):

In the United States, if you are VFR at an airport in Class G or E airspace, you may take off without needing clearance or permission from ATC.

Normally Class D airspace reverts to E or G outside of tower operating hours, therefore no communication with tower is required or even possible.